# Slow Boot on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: boot, grub2, 20.04, suspend

I upgraded from a previous version of Ubuntu to 20.4 LTS and the boot up takes minutes when it used to take seconds.
I get a lot of acpi errors but suspect these are a red herring.  Instead it eventually say "**giving up wait for resume/suspend device**".
I suspect that some configuration file has a UUID for a disk that doesn't exist any more.
This is borne out by running

```
> sudo update-initramfs -u
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-050800-generic
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=b022e3f7-de7c-476b-b7c2-a39efd0357c4
W: but no matching swap device is available.
```

I've been reading other posts and they point to a file in

> /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume

But that file doesn't existing on my system.

I've tried running **grub-update** but that didn't help either.

I have a swap file and not a swap partition.

My fstab file is as  follows:

```
    # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=ba512821-d4d7-40b7-80ab-f0279faf6092 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
#/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
# data disks
UUID=0d8a1c3c-5528-47cf-8dab-b7d642607764   /media/BigDisk  ext4    defaults    0   0
UUID=311c73fa-ed98-44da-b82a-03d2a347f17a   /media/Data ext4    defaults    0   0

#
# load home partition
#
UUID=ada9c853-51f9-4703-a107-42c26222b3be   /home    ext4          nodev,nosuid       0       2

#
# load swapfile 
#
/media/Data/swapfile    swap    swap    defaults 0 0
```

Where could the UUID be hiding ?

Comment: Are you certain that your swap definition in `fstab` is correct? Generally that first `swap` reads as `none`. `defaults` is typically either `defaults` or `sw` 

Comment: Have you looked at /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf ?

Comment: I don’t have a directory called initramfs-tools under /etc

Comment: I will check the definition for the swap file but from my understanding it doesn’t have a uuid or is that incorrect?

Comment: Is there a initramfs.conf file anywhere under /etc ?

Comment: I checked again and found the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume file. Think user error meant I couldn't find it.  I deleted the file and rebooted and the delay booting was gone.  Thanks for the points above.

Answer (score 0):

Resume file is located in /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/
I deleted this file and it solved the problem.  It appears to store the UUID of the partition where the suspended machine has been saved.